# Custom template for selected option in mat-select?

Tags: html, angular, mat-select

Customizing how your `mat-option`s look inside your `mat-select` is pretty straightforward:

```
<mat-option>
  black text
  <span style="color: red;">
    red text
  </span>
</mat-option>
```

However, this doesn't carry over to the option displayed once it is selected:

[image: No color changes in the selected option]

I see that I can make changes to the dropdown panel by adding them before the `mat-option` list, or using the `panelClass` attribute for styling; but I don't see anything to allow me to customize how the selected option is displayed. Is there any way to customize the contents of the selected option?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the view value of the option, you can subscribe to `selectionChange` output, and then change the view value of a specific option appropriately. If you want to have specific styles you can build on the `selected` prop of the option as well

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure out how to do this - it's just that `mat-select-trigger` isn't exactly the most intuitive name for this element. But put your custom template inside the `mat-select-trigger`, and it works perfectly:

```
<mat-select>
  <mat-select-trigger>
    black text
    <span style="color: red;">
      red text
    </span>
  </mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option>
    black text
    <span style="color: red;">
      red text
    </span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

[image: Multi-colored selected option]